# Pass an object or string via calling method of dynamic hyperlink click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, dynamic, hyperlink

```
     hyperLink = "<a href='#' id='hplinkactionUrl_" + options.rowId + "' onclick='" + options.colModel.CallMethod + "(" + options.rowId + ")' style='text-decoration:underline; color:#3361b8;'>" + cellvalue + "</a>"
return hyperLink;
```

This is my code. I am passing an integer now. I need to pass an object. If I pass an object, its taking it as string "[Object object]". Please help.

Making it a json works. However, I have another issue, I am trying to pass a string as well. Like:

```
hyperLink = "<a href='#' id='hplinkactionUrl_" + options.rowId + "' onclick='" + options.colModel.CallMethod + "(" + options.rowId + ",\"" + cellvalue + "\")' style='text-decoration:underline; color:#3361b8;'>" + cellvalue + "</a>"
```

This works. But when I pass a string(path) like "\ServerName\FolderName\File", I lose the backslashes"\" in calling method. Please help.

Comment: did you try passing your object as JSON.stringify('your object') ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize your object into a string somehow and to deserialize it back in click handler. You could use [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) for that.

```
encodeURI(JSON.stringify(SOME_OBJECT))
```

This will get you an url-encoded string with serialized object as a parameter for your `CallMethod`.

```
hyperLink = "<a href='#' id='hplinkactionUrl_" + options.rowId + "' onclick='" + options.colModel.CallMethod + "(" + escape(JSON.stringify(options)) + ")' style='text-decoration:underline; color:#3361b8;'>" + cellvalue + "</a>"
```

Use `JSON.parse(decodeURI(serialized_object)))` to get it back inside `CallMethod`.

Comment: Using escape showed me an error. Removing that, worked. Thanks. making it a json works. However, I have another issue, I am trying to pass a string as well. Like:  onclick='" + options.colModel.CallMethod + "(" + options.rowId + ",\"" + cellvalue + "\")'.. This works. Buw when I pass a string like "\\ServerName\FolderName\File", I lose the "\" in calling method. Please help.

Comment: `escape()` is there to avoid problems with the resulting html code. If the values in your object contain strings with quotes, the resulting json string will break the link code, because you are using a json string as an attribute value. Try using `encodeURI()` and `decodeURI()` instead of escape/unescape. As to the problem with back slashes in string literals, escape them with additional back slashes. So, "\\" will give you a **single** slash (the first slash will 'escape' the second). "\\\\" will give you two slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the object to a JSON string then on the next page PARSE this string. Though it might be easier to simply use session storage.

1) JSON.stringify(object) then

2) JSON.parse(string)

Though if the object has functions in it then stringify won't process those.

Comment: Thanks. making it a json works. However, I have another issue, I am trying to pass a string as well. Like:  onclick='" + options.colModel.CallMethod + "(" + options.rowId + ",\"" + cellvalue + "\")'.. This works. Buw when I pass a string like "\\ServerName\FolderName\File", I lose the "\" in calling method. Please help.

Comment: \ is usually an escape character, you have to use \\ to escape it, fiddle with different combinations until it works. That's my only guess.